# Rosh Hashanah and Zecher Liyitziyas Mitzrayim

Tags: rosh-hashanah-new-year

Rosh Hashanah is to my knowledge the Jewish New Year and the coronation of Hashem as our king amongst some of the reason for the Holiday yet we say in the [Kiddush](http://www.chabad.org/holidays/JewishNewYear/template_cdo/aid/418881/jewish/Kiddush.htm) it is a remembrance for leaving Egypt. How is it a remembrance for leaving Egypt what is the connection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gemara [Rosh Hashana 11a](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9718&st=&pgnum=23) says that on Rosh Hashana the servitude ended in Egypt. Therefore it is a day of remembrance as it was the beginning of leaving Egypt.