# How is Rosh Hashanah a remembrance of leaving Mitzraim?

Tags: tefilla, rosh-hashanah-new-year, yetziat-mitzrayim

On all Yamim Tovim, we (this is the Ashkenazic formulation) say the following formulation in the middle Bracha of Shemoneh Esrei:

> ותתן לנו ה׳ אלקינו באהבה את יום ... הזה ... מקרא קדש זכר ליציאת מצרים
>
> And You, HaShem, our G-d, gave us with love this day of , , a holy calling, a remembrance of leaving Egypt.

By nickname, I refer to Zeman Cheiruseinu for Pesach, Zeman Mattan Toraseinu for Shavuos, etc.

Notice the final line - a remembrance of leaving Egypt. This line remains even on Rosh Hashanah and Yom Kippur.

Now, Pesach is obvious why we have this. Shavuos is the culmination of the process begun on Pesach, and Sukkos/Shemini Atzeres is also related, also dealing with Hashem’s succeeding kindness to us in our trek from Mitzraim to Eretz Yisrael.

Yom Kippur I could even hear someone saying was when we got the second Luchos and is therefore related.

But Rosh Hashanah seems really out of place. Why is Rosh Hashanah a remembrance of leaving Mitzraim? What connection does Rosh Hashanah have?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rosh Hashanah and Zecher Liyitziyas Mitzrayim](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/30938/rosh-hashanah-and-zecher-liyitziyas-mitzrayim)

Comment: @mods I might be biased here, but I think this question and the answers therein are much more fleshed out than the question flagged than a dupe. It certainly is, but should it be marked the other way around instead?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [Shibbolei HaLeket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zedekiah_ben_Abraham_Anaw) (286) quotes his brother [R. Binyamin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benjamin_ben_Abraham_Anaw) as asking this question about Rosh HaShana and Yom HaKippurim. He quotes his brother's answer that the Talmud ([Rosh Hashanah 11a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=9&daf=11&format=pdf)) states that on Rosh HaShana the slave labour of the Jews ended in Egypt.

> ותירץ בראש השנה נמי ראוי לומר זכר ליציאת מצרים לפי מה ששנינו בראש השנה תניא ר' אליעזר אומר...בראש השנה בטלה עבודה מאבותינו במצרים...וביום הכיפורים נמי מצינו יציאת מצרים גבי שילוח עבדים...אמר ר' ישמעאל בנו של ר' יוחנן בן ברוקה מראש השנה ועד יום הכיפורים לא היו העבדים נפטרין לבתיהן ולא משתעבדין לאדוניהם אלא אוכלין ושותין ושמחין ועטרותיהן בראשיהן מראש השנה עד יום הכיפורים כיון שהגיע יום הכיפורים תקעו בית דין בשופר נפטרו העבדים לבתיהן ושדות חוזרות לבעליהן וגבי שילוח עבדים כתיב כי עבדי הם אשר הוצאתי אותם מארץ מצרים וגו' הא למדת שבראש השנה ויום הכיפורים נמי שייך לומר זכר ליציאת מצרים

The [Taz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_HaLevi_Segal) explains in his Divrei David [to Parashat Vaethanan](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14717&st=%D7%96%D7%9B%D7%A8%20%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%99%D7%90%D7%AA&pgnum=413&hilite=) that God redeemed us from servitude from Egypt and made us his slaves. However, while the Egyptians made us work, God commanded us to rest on holidays. Accordingly, we can say זכר ליציאת מצרים on all holidays including Rosh HaShana, since when refraining from labour, we remember the exodus:

> דבמה שנצטוינו לשבות בהם מכל מלאכה אנו עבדים שלו ובזה נזכר החסד של
>   יציאת מצרים שהיו שם עבדים ע"י מלאכה כבדה.

Incidentally, it isn't just Ashkenazim who include these words, Rambam [does as well](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/2700.htm#46).

Answer (score 0):

the possuk says אנכי ד' אל' אשר הוצאתיך מארץ מצרים and not אשר בראתיך which implies that our recognition of rosh hashanah being the day of our creation which is why we are being judged today stems from our experiencing of and gratefulness for our personal yetsias mitsraim.This is brought  out by one of the Rishonim on the possuk.we find this concept as an explanation by chazal on how פרעה came to כפירה and that was through his forgetting of the good that yosef has done for them   . well then our acknowledgement of ראש השנה is one and the same as of ראש השנה THE KEY BEING BE GRATEFUL TO TRUST AND TRUST ME YOU CAN BE GRATEFUL

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya Avraham. Consider learning more about the site from this short  useful [Beginners  Guide](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/8775).

Comment: Welcome to MY! I’m not exactly sure how this answers the question. Perhaps you can explain a little more clearly? Also, I highly recommend reading the link mevaqesh cited. Hope to see you around!