# The Orchos Tzaddikim in Shaar HaSimcha: What does Purim have to do with remembering the Exodus?

Tags: purim, mussar-ethics, yetziat-mitzrayim

The [Orchos Tzaddikim](https://www.sefaria.org/Orchot_Tzadikim.9.75?lang=bi) in the end of *Shaar HaSimcha* writes:

(Source from *[Sefaria.org](https://www.sefaria.org/)*)

> גם צריך לשמוח בשבתות וימים טובים **ופורים, כי כולם לזכר יציאת מצרים** ולזכר הנסים שהפליא עם בחיריו
>
> *It is also necessary to rejoice on Sabbaths, Festivals **and on Purim because all of them are a memorial to our exodus from Egypt** and of the miracles which He has done wondrously with His chosen ones.*

## My Question:

What does Purim have to do with remembering the Exodus from Egypt<sup>1</sup>?

---

<sub>1. While it can also be asked "What does the Sabbath have to do with remembering the Exodus?" or "What do the festivals have to do with remembering the Exodus?" the connection between Purim and remembering the Exodus is what intrigues the author of this question.</sub>

Comment: Maybe it's not "and of the miracles" but "or of the miracles" (the same way you use "and" in "the stop lights I could see were all red and green; no yellows to be found")

Comment: Huh. I'm not sure why this is downvoted

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/30938/

Comment: The words  ולזכר הנסים could be read  וּלזכר הנסים and then you have a question, or   או לזכר הנסים  and then you have no question.

Answer (score 5):

In the commentary of Alei Orach on Orchos Tzadikim, he suggests:
1 - "כולם" is referring to all but Purim.
2 - On Purim we accepted the Torah voluntarily, "קימו וקיבלו היהודים" which was the ultimate goal of Yitzias Mitzrayim.

Answer (score 2):

It is explained in [Sefer Kehillat Yaacov Erech Heh"Mem:2 and 8 discussing Haman](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=44143&st=&pgnum=83) by Rabbi Yaacov Tzvi Yolles, that many of the central characters in the story of Purim are reincarnations of the players in the exodus from Egypt.

Haman is a descendent from Amalek (עמלק), *the fruit of Amalek*. Amalek is from the spiritual root of the Nachash found in Bereshit. This is based upon the prophecy of Isaiah 14:29 which says:

> אל־תשמחי פלשת כלך כי נשבר שבט מכך כי־משרש **נחש יצא צפע** ופריו שרף מעופף

That צפע is gematria Amalek. And on the side of holiness, Mordechai is the gilgul of Moshe Rabbeinu. Rabbi Yolles points out that the *Roshei Teivot* of Haman (המן) is המן משורש נחש, that Haman, like his ancestor Amalek, is from the root of the Nachash.

It’s interesting to note from his full name in Megillat Esther (המן בן המדתא האגגי) that the *Mispar Katan* with the 4 words of his name (a sum of 56) equals the *Mispar Katan* of שרף מעופף when including the 8 letters and 2 words. That complies with both details in the posuk from Isaiah, that Amalek is from the root of the Nachash and Haman is (Amalek’s fruit) his descendent.

And all this concept that Purim is in memory of the Exodus from Egypt follows the idea presented in [Shavuot 39a](https://www.sefaria.org/Shevuot.39a.10?lang=bi) that Purim is when the Jewish people fulfilled that which they accepted at the giving of the Torah. Like it says:

> ואין לי אלא מצוה שקיבלו עליהם מהר סיני מצות העתידות להתחדש כגון מקרא מגילה מנין ת"ל (אסתר ט, כז) **קימו וקבלו קיימו מה שקבלו**

Comment: Does anyone have any thoughts about the relationship of Haman, שרף מעופף which means a ‘flying serpent’ AKA a dragon, and Draco, the Dragon constellation?

Answer (score 1):

1)in the targum sheni it says.....
haman on the way to hanging told mordechai !!
you just had miracles done just like in mitzrayim 
is it not enough?

it seems even amalek agreed that purim is a copy of those miracles in egypt

2)gemara megillah says .....
the posuk of “ oh hanissa .... goy meekerevv  goy”
means purim

maharsha asks !! that’s mitzrayim?
he there explains why purim is same

Comment: Where in the Targum Sheni does it mention that?

Comment: look at the posuk of ויאמר המלך  תלוהו עליו

Answer (score 0):

There is a discussion in the Ramban at the end of Parshas Bo (Shmos 13:16) explaining why the Torah connected many Mitzvos with יציאת מצרים.
He explains the principle of miracles done for the benefit of Am Yisrael, and their connection with יציאת מצרים.

Thus, the miracle of Purim also is connected with יציאת מצרים.