# What about Yetziat Mitzrayim should I remember?

Tags: tefilla, yetziat-mitzrayim, kavana-concentration

One of the [שש זכירות](http://mobile.tora.ws/html/2220201-26.html) requires that I remember the Exodus from Egypt ([זכירת יציאת מצרים](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%A9_%D7%96%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA)). According to the linked Wiki document, in an effort to fulfill
 (לְמַעַן תִּזְכֹּר אֶת יוֹם צֵאתְךָ מֵאֶרֶץ מִצְרַיִם כֹּל יְמֵי חַיֶּיךָ: (דברים ט"ז, I say the third perek of the Sh'ma (though many other things all seem to be marking that remembrance as well).‏

In one sense, I remember the specific date (as stated [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/30938/rosh-hashanah-and-zecher-liyitziyas-mitzrayim)) or the literal fact that I left/am leaving (sort of [here](https://www.torahweb.org/torah/2018/moadim/rsob_pesach.html)). In another sense, I mark all the things that the exodus led up to (or to the echoes of the events) as discussed [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/92014/the-orchos-tzaddikim-in-shaar-hasimcha-what-does-purim-have-to-do-with-remember), or the exodus as a foundation for the ability to do everything else in my life ([here](https://www.ou.org/torah/machshava/change-your-pesach-change-your-life/pesach-all-year-unexpected-mitzvot-of-remembering-egypt/), sort of). But I am not clear, though, on what I am remembering in order to be mekayem this (Rabbinic) mitzvah/obligation.

Am I remembering an event, a change in status, God's general power or something else? In the preparatory [prayer](https://www.hidabroot.org/%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9F) before donning my tefillin I say וְשֶׁנִּזְכֹּר נִסִּים וְנִפְלָאוֹת שֶׁעָשָׂה עִמָּנוּ בְּהוֹצִיאָנוּ מִמִּצְרָיִם that I am remembering the miracles and wonders done then. What should I be focusing on?

Comment: Ultimately, the actual taking out itself.

Comment: I think your remembering the "Cheirus" which means using all the Serving Hashem and not get distracted through various chores that take over your life and Distract you from Serving Hashem, See Mesilas Yesharim Introduction

Comment: I think the main thing is to be aware that *Yetziat Mitrayim* was done as a necessary perquisite to coming to Har Sinai and receiving the Torah, which in turn, obligated us and defined the list of *mitzvot*. One pasuk, hits me, now. It's at the end of parshat Bo, which says, "Remember this day when you left Egypt from the house of bondage, because with the strength of His hand God took you out from here..." I have a hunch that mefarshim expound on this first occurrence of the requirement to remember the Exodus. I'll try to explore there, and, perhaps, you might notice something as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Rabbi Levi Yitzchak Schneerson](https://www.chabad.org/therebbe/article_cdo/aid/117515/jewish/Biography-of-Rabbi-Levi-Yitzchak.htm), the father of the Lubavitcher Rebbe [(Likkutei Sichot, volume 21, p. 71)](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14944&st=&pgnum=84&hilite=) explains that "so that you may remember the day of your departure from the land of Egypt as long as you live" [(Devarim 16:3)](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.16.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)- is to teach us to remember that we are out of exile, we have left Mitzrayim, we have left the bondage of Pharaoh.

The Gemara [(Berachos 14b)](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.14b.10?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) is teaching us something similair, however in a different context:

> Who took us out from Egypt and redeemed us from the house of bondage

The Alter Rebbe [(beginning of chapter 47 of Tanya, Likkutei Amarim)](https://www.chabad.org/library/tanya/tanya_cdo/aid/1029127/jewish/Chapter-47.htm) teaches us that the teaching of both the Gemara and Mishnah [(Pesachim 116b and 10:5-6)](https://www.sefaria.org/Pesachim.116b.3?lang=bi&with=Mishnah%20Pesachim&lang2=en), that in every generation, a person must view himself as though he personally left Egypt, means that you must remember that the divine soul was released from the "serpent's skin"- the bondage:

> "In every generation and every day a person is obliged to regard himself as if he had that day come out of Egypt." This refers to the release of the divine soul from the confinement of the body, the "serpent's skin," in order to be absorbed into the Unity of the light of the blessed En Sof, through occupation in the Torah and commandments in general, and in particular through accepting the Kingdom of Heaven during the recital of the Shema, wherein the person explicitly accepts and draws over himself His blessed Unity, when he says: "The Lord is our G‑d, the Lord is One."

See also [Maamar Kimei Tzeischa Mei'eretz Mitzrayim - Part II from the Lubavitcher Rebeb](https://www.chabad.org/therebbe/article_cdo/aid/145219/jewish/Part-II.htm):

> The daily remembrance of the exodus from Egypt focuses primarily on one dimension of exo­dus, departing from the straits of unholiness; it highlights the exodus from the limitations that hinder Torah study and impede the performance of the mitzvos.

@DanF in his comment states "I think the main thing is to be aware that Yetziat Mitrayim was done as a necessary perquisite to coming to Har Sinai and receiving the Torah, which in turn, obligated us and defined the list of mitzvot". According to the Rebbe, this is true. The Rebbe explains that the rememberance of the Exodus highlights the exodus from the limitations that hinder Torah study and impede the performance of the mitzvos.

However, according to Rabbi Eliezer Melamed in his [Peninei Halakhah (Pesach 15:2)](https://www.sefaria.org/Peninei_Halakhah%2C_Pesach.15.2.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), the mitzvah of "remembering the exodus" can be fullfilled by praying Shema twice a day:

> To fulfill the obligation to invoke the Exodus every day and night, we recite the third paragraph of Shema each morning and evening, as this paragraph states: “I am the L-rd your G-d Who has taken you out of Egypt to be your G-d: I am the L-rd your G-d” (Bamidbar 15:41).

Answer (score 0):

That that event was foundational; it made us into His people and Him into our God. [Shemos (Exodus) 20:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.20.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en).

Answer (score 0):

Some points and references I found in an index to Likutei Halakhot by R' Nathan z"l:

Recalling/mentioning Yetziat Misrayim in the Tzitzit paragraph of Kriat Shema - because the essence of Emunah that we receive in Kriat Shema is through the aspect of Tzitzit, as by Tzitzit one gets privileged to draw close to the Tzaddik, as the essence of Emunah is by him, see there. ["And they believed in Hashem and in Moshe his servant"]
: - Likutei Halakhot O"C Hodaah #2

Recalling/mentioning Y"M - in order to draw on oneself the sanctity of Y"M even right now, every day, and to merit to the aspect of receiving the Torah, namely performing the Torah.
: - L"H Y"D Yayin Nesekh #4:21

Recalling/mentioning Y"M - the aspect of elevating the Nefesh over the body; the aspect of Life etc.
: - L"H Y"D Chadash #3:5